# Como faço para mudar a legenda de um gráfico?

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em c# usando o gráfico do Windows Form. Gostaria de saber como faço para colocar os valores do eixo x como a legenda do mesmo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
string[] nomes = { "eduardo", "jorge", "chris", "matheus" };
int[] idades = { 23, 10, 70, 80 };

List<int> numeros = new List<int>();
numeros.Add(23);
numeros.Add(10);
numeros.Add(70);
numeros.Add(100);
int maior = numeros.Max();
int menor = numeros.Min();
chart1.Titles.Add("Idades");

for (int i = 0; i < nomes.Length; i++)
{

    //chart1.Series["Idades"]["PointWidth"] = "0.6";

    //chart1.Series.Add(nomes[i]);

    chart1.Legends.Add(new Legend(nomes[i]));

    chart1.Series["Idades"].Points.AddXY(nomes[i], idades[i]);

    if(numeros.ElementAt(i)==maior){

       chart1.Series["Idades"].Points[i].Color = Color.Red;

    }else if (numeros.ElementAt(i) == menor) {

       chart1.Series["Idades"].Points[i].Color = Color.Yellow;
    }
    else
    {
       chart1.Series["Idades"].Points[i].Color = Color.Blue;
     }
}
```

Comment: Coloque seu código também, assim fica melhor para a comunidade ajudar vc.

Comment: Sim, provavelmente o que você tem que fazer é usar o Legends.add para cada valor do vetor do eixo X.

Comment: Eu tentei isso: chart1.Series["Idades"].LegendText = "#VALX", mas não deu certo

Answer (score 0):

Dessa forma você pode renomear a legenda do Chart.

```
this.ChartLinhas.Series[0].Name = tiposLinhas.ToString();
this.ChartLinhas.Legends[0].Name = tiposLinhas.ToString();
this.ChartLinhas.Series[0].Legend = tiposLinhas.ToString();
```